# Unity 3d Rigidbody moving but not child object

Tags: unity-game-engine, parent-child, gameobject, child-objects

I have made a car scene in Unity. I have one `Rigidbody` (car) and its `childgameobject`. I made a script to move that `childgameobject` with sliders while `Rigidbody` is moving. The `childgameobject` moves fine with the slider but when my `Rigidbody` moves, the child `GameObject` remains in the same position and doesn't move with `Rigidbody`. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChildMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider MySliderx;
    public Slider MySlidery;
    public Slider MySliderz;
    public Transform Cam;
    public float temp;

    private float CamInitialY = 0f;
    private float CamInitialX = 0f;
    private float CamInitialZ = 0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        CamInitialY = Cam.transform.position.y;
        CamInitialX = Cam.transform.position.x;
        CamInitialZ = Cam.transform.position.z;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Cam.transform.position = new Vector3 (Cam.position.x, CamInitialY + MySliderx.value , Cam.position.z);
        Cam.transform.position = new Vector3 (CamInitialX + MySlidery.value, Cam.position.y, Cam.position.z);
        Cam.transform.position = new Vector3 (Cam.position.x, Cam.position.y, CamInitialZ + MySliderz.value);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing position to localposition.